# ggplot2 Histogram Using Pre-Computed Counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have pre-computed counts by value.  I would like to turn those into a histogram, preferably using `ggplot2`.  The plot below is not what I want, since I would like to be able to adjust the bins similarly to how I would using the `bins` argument in `geom_histogram()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# define data.frame
df <-
  data.frame(
            value = c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,
                      19,2,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28),
    num_customers = c(208,179,232,335,263,277,32898,
                      325,332,461,3441,415,19584,392,521,513,674,24114,
                      807,692)
  )

# print data.frame
df
#>    value num_customers
#> 1     10           208
#> 2     11           179
#> 3     12           232
#> 4     13           335
#> 5     14           263
#> 6     15           277
#> 7     16         32898
#> 8     17           325
#> 9     18           332
#> 10    19           461
#> 11     2          3441
#> 12    20           415
#> 13    21         19584
#> 14    22           392
#> 15    23           521
#> 16    24           513
#> 17    25           674
#> 18    26         24114
#> 19    27           807
#> 20    28           692

# make ugly bar plot
df %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = value,
      y = num_customers
    )
  ) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You may think your plot is 'ugly', but unlike a histogram, it shows the exact distribution of your data.

Comment: @Allan Cameron, I can see the exact distribution by changing the number of bins in the histogram.  The bar plot is limited to exactly one bin per value.  It's often illustrative to change the number of bins and see what patterns emerge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Histograms are univariate plots meant to estimate underlying densities for continuous random variables. They are not really meant for count data. But you can "uncount" your data to turn it into a single variable and treat it like a continuous variable (though your data looks like it's more discrete than continous).

```
df %>% 
  tidyr::uncount(num_customers) %>% 
  ggplot() + aes(value) + geom_histogram(bins=10)
```

[image]